# Convert __ComObject to underlying object type

Tags: c#, interop, excel-interop

I can cast a com object with no problem, such as:

```
ChartObject chart = selection as ChartObject;
```

But if I try to look at the properties in selection using reflection, it fails because, while ChartObjects has a Parent property, __ComObject does not.

Is there a way to turn this object from the __ComObject into the ChartObject type. And in this case, at runtime I can get several different object types so I can't do a cast in code, I need to use reflection.

Comment: You never actually cast to an "object type", COM uses a hyper-pure interface-based programming paradigm.  ChartObject is a type that comes from the Office interop library, C# is friendly enough to make it an alias for the default interface implemented by the real object, `_ChartObject`.  The `__ComObject` type is a wrapper for the RCW, "runtime callable wrapper".  It does little by itself, but provide the ability make the cast work.  QueryInterface() under the hood.  "Do you know how to do this" => "yes I do".  Ably implemented in C# v4 with the `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: @HansPassant - Can you please provide me a url to an explanation or example of how to do this? What you say makes sense, but I need to get that object it turns into when accessed as the underlying(?) type. thanks - dave